# Add hyphen or underscore between two int

Tags: c#

I am trying to get some Id's from a database. If I get one value it works as expected however I want my method to return more than one value. For example

If, `Id1 = 1 and Id2 = 2` I want to display it as `1-2` or `1_2`. I can't seem to figure out how I would put the hyphen `-` or underscore `_` between two `int`. My code is below

```
public int GetId()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {

        string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        UserInfo info = new UserInfo();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstId, SecondId FROM MyTable WHERE UserName=@userName"))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", userName);
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    info.FirstId = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    info.SecondId = reader.GetInt32(1);
                }
            }
        }
        return info.FirstId + "_" + info.SecondId;
    }
}
```

My `UserInfo` class has basic `Get and Set` properties. I have only come across `Tuple` today. I've tried using `Tuple` but I get values displayed as `(1,2)`. With `Tuple` of course I can add underscore `_` or a hyphen `-` but the problem is I can't get rid of the brackets `()`and the comma `,` that separates the values. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance for your help and support.

Comment: an integer can't have an underscore. you need to return a string

Comment: if you want to return 2 values, why not just return the `UserInfo` instance you already populated? if you want it as a string, the return type of the method shouldn't be an int

Comment: Your method returns and `int`, but if you concat it with "_" or "-", you have a string. Further, why not return a `List<int>` or an array or just the UserInfo?

Comment: You can create your own class simillar to Tuple and override its ToString method

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you were explaining why you'd want to do this. It seems relatively strange to have two IDs and trying to hyphenate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method claims to return an `int`:

```
public int GetId()
```

but sort of attempts to return a `string`:

```
return info.FirstId + "_" + info.SecondId;
```

A hyphen or an underscore means it's no longer a numeric data type, it's now just a string.  So you'd have to return it as a string:

```
public string GetId()
{
    // etc.

    return string.Format("{0}_{1}", info.FirstId, info.SecondId);
}
```

If you want the data to still be structured in some way, then as you suggest a `Tuple<int, int>` would do the trick:

```
public Tuple<int, int> GetId()
{
    // etc.

    return new Tuple<int, int>(info.FirstId, info.SecondId);
}
```

Then it would be up to the consuming code to decide how to display it:

```
var id = GetId();
Console.Write(string.Format("{0}_{1}", id.Item1, id.Item2));
```

This also means that you'd be using very unintuitive names like `Item1` and `Item2`.  If you want something more aptly named, you can introduce a custom object:

```
public class IDs
{
    public int FirstId { get; set; }
    public int SecondId { get; set; }
}
```

Then just return an instance of that.  This approach has some added advantages:

- You can rename `FirstId` and `SecondId` to more meaningful names
- You can make the object immutable by making the setters `private` and adding a constructor which accepts the values
- You can override `.ToString()` to give it a default `string` representation with the underscore

For example:

```
public class IDs
{
    public int FirstId { get; private set; }
    public int SecondId { get; private set; }

    private IDs() { }

    public IDs(int firstId, int secondId)
    {
        FirstId = firstId;
        SecondId = secondId;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}_{1}", FirstId, SecondId);
    }
}
```

Then return an instance of that:

```
public IDs GetId()
{
    // etc.

    return new IDs(info.FirstId, info.SecondId);
}
```

And consuming code can just display it as-is, since its string representation is internally defined:

```
var id = GetId();
Console.Write(id);
```